# update-rc.d yields error

Tags: debian, nginx

```
# /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing
```

How to fix it?

Comment: What are you asking, exactly? At any rate, you're probably better off asking at http://www.superuser.com since this doesn't seem like a programming question.

Comment: /usr/sbin/update-rc.d -f nginx defaults

this doesn't work,but show me an error:
update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing

Answer (score 2):

`update-rc.d: using dependency based boot sequencing` is not an error. It's telling you it's using new dependency based booting instead of old sequence-based booting.

If /etc/rc3.d/SXXnginx exists, then it worked. Also, what version of Debian are you using? The `-f` flag should only be used when removing a startup item, not for adding one. Or are you trying to remove it? Your question could be a little more clear.